# How to use NavLink in conformation prompt

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've given my code below.

```
 confirmAlert({
    buttons: [
      {
        label: 'Yes',
        onClick: () => {
          <NavLink
            to={`/upload/data`}
          ></NavLink>
        }
      },
      {
        label: 'No',
        onClick: () => {
          console.log('Click No');
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

In the above code Conformation popup is not displayed. It is throwing error "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions". Whenever I remove NavLink tag it is working. How do i change my code with Navlink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use [history.push](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory)

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
let history = useHistory();
...
onClick: () => history.push('/upload/data');
...
```

Comment: Without hooks is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @shanthiJagadeesh The answer below is the second paragraph using `withRouter` HOC https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Comment: Thank you so much ... Works Perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are asking regarding React Router.
Depending whether your component is functional or not, the following solutions might be suitable:

**1) Your component is functional**

You can declare a hook in the beginning of your component:

```
let history = useHistory();
```

and then in your function you can do:

```
onClick: () => {
          history.push(`/upload/data`)
        }
```

**2) You are using a class component:**

export your component with router:

```
export default withRouter(yourComponent);
```

and then you can access history from props:

```
onClick: () => {
          this.props.history.push(`/upload/data`)
        }
```

Comment: Without hooks is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @shanthiJagadeesh yes, please look at the second paragraph in my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much..Works perfect :)

Comment: @shanthiJagadeesh please accept the answer :) thanks